# How do i set a field as constant in the constructor

Tags: java, constants, subclass, final

So I have a Person class with a name, address, age, and email address. A subclass Student of Person that has a "class status (freshmen, sophomore, junior, senior)". I have to define the status as a constant.

```
class Student extends Person{
    private String classStatus;

    public Student(String name, String address, int age, String email,
final String classStatus){
        super(name, address, age, email);
        this.classStatus = classStatus;}
```

Is there anything particularly wrong with this? Eclipse doesn't give me any errors, but, I feel like my variable isn't actually set as a constant. Basically, when I construct a Student object, I want to also include either "freshmen" "sophomore" "junior" or "senior" in the parameters and it'll set classStatus as a constant.

As I was writing this, I realized that if I don't provide a set method for the classStatus, is it inherently a constant already? Is this due to it being private?

Answer (score 3):

> As I was writing this, I realized that if I don't provide a set method
>   for the classStatus, is it inherently a constant already? Is this due
>   to it being private?

It's not a proper way of doing, declare your variable `classStatus` as `final`

```
private final String classStatus;
```

In this case, You have to provide the `classStatus`, when you create an instance of Student, and thereafter, it can't be changed for that instance.